# stop parsley js firing keyup when tabbing

Tags: jquery, parsley.js

I have some fields that have keyup and blur events set on them. All works great with parsley js for validation until it comes to when a user tabs into a field that has a keyup on it. Then it triggers the error right away when they user is tabbed into the field. So before the user even gets to enter anything they get an error. Is there a way to stop this from happening obviously without removing the keyup event.

```
 <input type="text" value="" placeholder="XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX" class="card" id="card" name="number" pattern="[0-9]*" data-trigger="blur keyup" data-required="true" data-validation-minlength="0" >
```

- Right now you click into the input field, then click out again error
  is triggered with the blur event.
- Click into the filed start to type if the user types incorrect
  value keyup will fire.

The above all work great.

- Click into an input field before the card filed then tab to card input filed
  which is the next index then keyup is fired right away.

The above scenario is the one I want to stop happening until the user keyups inside the input field.

Answer (score 0):

Ok for anyone who runs into this issue this is one way to sort it out.
Set a focusin event on the card input. Make sure you don't use this in your parsley event-trigger attribute. Then remove parsley checking for this event on the focusin event. Then set a timeout so you can replace it back in after parsley has gotten over it's initial required validation.

Kind of hacky I know and I don't like using timers but in this case it works. I tried 100 and that worked for all browsers except IE so I had to increase to 200 for IE compensation.

```
$('.card').focusin(function(){

    $('form').parsley( 'removeItem', '#card' );
    setTimeout(function(){
        getCurrentForm().parsley( 'addItem', '#card' );
    },200);
});
```

Hope this helps someone as any questions I ever ask about Parsley I never get a reply. Seems like Parsley is not common questions. For anyone who hasn't used Parsley js it's and amazing validation library that you should checkout.